# Joomla 2.5, jquery hide() not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

I need to `hide/show` div's with jquery in Joomla 2.5. I included the `*.js` files in `default.php` template with:

```
<?php
JHTML::script('jquery-1.11.0.min.js', 'templates/mytemplate/js/');
JHTML::script('bbbx.js', 'templates/mytemplate/js/');
?>
```

I have a simple div in my default.php template:

```
<div class="myclass" id="myid">
    <h1>Hallo</h1>
</div>
```

And my `bbbx.js` file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        alert("Your alert.");
        $("div.myclass").hide();
});
```

The `bbbx.js` file is found, alert is showing, but `hide()` doesn't work. The same code works perfectly well without Joomla. Please help, what is the problem here?

Comment: can you alert `alert(jQuery === $)`, also check whether the element is present using `alert($("div.myclass").length)`

Comment: Most probably `$` is colliding with another library and you would have to use `noConflict` method.

Comment: `alert(jQuery === $)` shows 'false' and `alert($("div.myclass").length)` is not coming up at all...

Comment: <script src="/newbbbx/plugins/system/jsntplframework/assets/joomlashine/js/noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script> is loaded by my template, but it is loading after my script. Should it be before my scripts? Where can I change the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, I added my script directly to default.php in `<script></script>` tag (and now it is loaded after noconflict.js), and it is working now. I don't know whether it is a correct approach of Joomla because it is not listed under http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript , but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a jQuery confliction. `alert()` works of course because it is not related to jQuery. It is a standard javascript function.

Try this please;

```
var myjq = jQuery.noConflict(); 
//myjq is just a suggestion you may try another word like vogele

myjq(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Your alert.");
    myjq("div.myclass").hide();
});
```

Also you must consider which jQuery library file comes first. Sometimes whne you change the `<script>` tags' order, the problem goes away.

Comment: @vogele can you please share your HTML output over jsfiddle?